# ¿como unir dos consultas select?

Tags: php, mysql

hola tengo un problema como puedo unir dos consultas select lo que pasa es que por ejemplo tengo esta consulta:

```
select vehiculo,fecha_carga,rendimiento_kilometro,rendimiento_real,ticket,factura,costo_total,empresa
from carga_combustible
where factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn'
order by fecha_carga desc
```

me da este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito sumar el campo costo total, entonces hago esto:

```
select vehiculo,fecha_carga,rendimiento_kilometro,rendimiento_real,ticket,factura,costo_total,empresa,sum(costo_total) as monto from carga_combustible where factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn' order by fecha_carga desc
```

pero al hacer eso se me desaparece la otra fila que tenia abajo y se muestra asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no quiero que suceda eso, quiero que se muestren mis dos filas y mi monto total , lo mismo pasa en mi tabla html cuando lo hago en php se me desaparece la otra fila , quiero que aparezcan las dos filas y abajo su total , como puedo hacer la consulta??? ya se que en mysql no va a aparecer abajo el total pero en html si pero lo pongo de ejemplo, no se si me entiendan , alguna sugerencia ? gracias.

Comment: Tratar de usar un GROUP BY vehiculo

Comment: puse lo que indicas al final de mi consulta si me muestra otra vez mi fila que se quito pero en el monto me muestra por separado las cantidades no las suma

Comment: Lo que yo he hecho en estos casos es generar la consulta para la tabla(así como tu lo hiciste), luego crear otra consulta que solo retorne la suma que quieres y ese valor lo pones en un control, por ejemplo un textbox

Comment: pues si es otra opción de hecho ya lo estaba haciendo así pero quería ver si existía alguna consulta u otra forma de hacerlo en una sola consulta o unir dos  y no generar consultas por separado

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de un sp? si es asi se puede hacer una logica y asi solo se llama al sp que te regrese la tabla como la necesitas, prueba con esto ...

Comment: select vehiculo,fecha_carga,rendimiento_kilometro,rendimiento_real,ticket,T.factura,costo_total,empresa,A.monto
from carga_combustible T
INNER JOIN (
select sum(costo_total) as monto,factura
from carga_combustible 
where factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn' 
GROUP BY factura
) A ON A.factura=T.factura
where T.factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn'
order by fecha_carga desc

Comment: @EdgarVazquez no puedo marcar tu respuesta como aceptada , pero funciono tu consulta muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda , que tipo de consulta es la que realizaste ? para documentarme mas al respecto

Comment: jeje te lo pongo como respuesta y te explico saludos

Comment: Te anexe info @JasielTorres saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te pongo la consulta que puedes usar

```
select vehiculo,fecha_carga,rendimiento_kilometro,rendimiento_real,ticket,T.factura,costo_total,empresa,A.monto
from carga_combustible T
INNER JOIN (
select sum(costo_total) as monto,factura
from carga_combustible 
where factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn' 
GROUP BY factura
) A ON A.factura=T.factura
where T.factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn'
order by fecha_carga desc
```

Lo que estamos haciendo en el JOIN es obtener el total ya que de otro modo no se puede acceder por que al sumarlo y agruparlo nos lo separa entonces en el JOIN agregamos la consulta para obtener el resultado y posteriormente lo igualamos a un campo de nuestra tabla en común en este caso la factura pero podria ser otro si asi lo quisieramos y ya con con eso podemos acceder al resultado esperado.

Son subquerys

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/subqueries/index.php

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación ya comprendí mejor la estructura de la consulta

Comment: De nada saludos :D